# SSD causing flickering when holding a key on the keyboard in games

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question.
I was using Ubuntu just fine but last weekend I did a clean install of winows 10. I relized then that when playing a video game, holding down a button makes it so as if I was tapping it repeatedly. I don't know if its only when playing or all t the time (I only noticed when playing games). I tried updating the SSD firmware and the graphics driver, tried activating AHCI in BIOS. but nothing worked. changing the keyboard repeat rate didn't help either.

Update:
I did a new clean installation of windows but this time only on the HHD. This fixed the problem so it is a problem with my ssd

Answer (score 1):

It is all the time. It's built in to the hardware.

---

From *Windows 2000 Resource Kit Reference, Technical Guide to the Registry*.

> **KeyboardDelay**
> HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard
>
> Data type Range Default value
> REG_SZ  0-3  1
>
> **Description**
>
> Determines how long after a key is pressed and held down that the key
> begins to repeat the character. The values 0 (shortest delay;
> approximately 250 milliseconds) and 3 (longest delay; approximately 1
> second) correspond to the four increments on the Repeat delay scale in
> Keyboard in Control Panel.
>
> **Change method**
>
> To change the value of this entry, use the Keyboard Properties box.
> Repeat delay is in the Character repeat box on the Speed tab.
>
> ---
>
> **KeyboardSpeed**
>
> ```
>  HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard
> ```
>
> Data type Range Default value
> REG_SZ  0-31  31
>
> **Description**
>
> Determines the rate at which a character repeats when you hold down a
> keyboard key. The values 0 (slowest repeat rate; approximately 2
> characters per second) through 31 (fastest repeat rate; approximately
> 30 characters per second) correspond to the 31 increments on the
> Repeat rate scale in Keyboard in Control Panel.
>
> **Change method**
>
> To change the value of this entry, use the Keyboard Properties box.
> Repeat rate is in the Character repeat box on the Speed tab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said in the quetion I already tried that and it didn't work